# How to access files on digital ocean spaces with multer

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, object-storage

I have managed to upload pdf files on digital ocean spaces with a node js app as shown below.
I don't know how to then access those files and display them to the user. I got the code below from this tutorial, [object storage file upload,](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-file-to-object-storage-with-node-js) but there isn't an example on how to then access the files. 
When I just try to access them with their url, I just get white space.
I have made them public but still get absolutely nothing trying to access them from the url.
Is there a way to access the files using multer still, do I have to make a get request with the RESTFul API? How do I access files stored in a digital ocean spaces?

This is how I upload files

```js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const spaceEndPoint = new aws.Endpoint("ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com");
const s3 = new aws.S3({
 endpoint:spaceEndPoint
})

const upload = multer({
 storage:multerS3({
  s3:s3,
  bucket: "fileRepo",
  acl:"public-read",
  key:function(request, file, cb){
   console.log(file);
   cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
 })
}).array("upload",1);

router.get("uploadFile", function(req,res){
 upload(req, res, function(error){
  if(error){
   console.log(error);
   return res.redirect("/");
  }
 });
})
```

And this is how I try to retrive the pdfs

```js
router.get("/contentPage", function(req, res){

 var fileName = req.body.department;
 var directory = "https://fileRepo.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/" + fileName + ".pdf";
 res.render("fileview", {dir: directory});
})
```

```html
<div id="departmentListWrapper" class="container">
 <embed src="<%= dir %>" width="800px" height="2100px" />
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue might be with retrieving these files?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet, works fine for me

```
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from 'multer-s3';

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'your access key',
  secretAccessKey: 'your secret key'
});
var filepath = "path of files folder"
// Create an S3 client setting the Endpoint to DigitalOcean Spaces
var spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com');
var s3 = new aws.S3({endpoint: spacesEndpoint});

  var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName, 
    Key: keyName, 
    Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.putObject(params, async function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that digital ocean did not know what type of file was being uploaded, I had to make it so that the file type is read before it is uploaded so that the browser knew what type of file I was trying to upload by adding the line

> contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE

to the multer object so that it looks like this.

```js
const upload = multer({
 storage:multerS3({
  s3:s3,
  bucket: "fileRepo",
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE
  acl:"public-read",
  key:function(request, file, cb){
   console.log(file);
   cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
 })
}).array("upload",1);
```